# How to do the sorting for duplicate numbers in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates

Now I want to do the sorting part...
What is sort?
And I so confused about sorting and I need to remove the duplicate numbers...
And how to do remove numbers and sort for this coding?
p/s:The duplicate numbers I only got a few...

```
import java.lang.*; 
// import java.util.Random;

class UniqueRandomIntArray {

//   static Random rnGen = new Random();

   private static void uriArray(int[] rray) {
      int low = 0;
      int high = 100;

      int rn;
      int haveit = -1;
      int i = 0; 
      int j;

      while((haveit == -1) && i < rray.length) {  
         rn = randNum(low, high);

         for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if(rn == rray[j]) {
               haveit = j;
               j = i;
               }
            }

         if(haveit != -1) {
            System.out.println("a[" + haveit + "] is " + rn + " already");
            haveit = -1;
            }
         else {
            System.out.println("a[" + i + "] is " + rn);
            rray[i] = rn;
            i++;
            }

         }   // end while
      }      // end uriArray


   private static int randNum(int min, int max) {
      int range = (max - min) + 1;
//      int randnum = rnGen.nextInt(range) + min;
      int randnum = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
      return randnum;
      }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arra = new int[20];
      uriArray(arra);
      for(int i=0; i<arra.length; i++)  {
         System.out.print(" | " + arra[i]);
         }
      System.out.println(" | ");
      }

   } //class ends
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441276/duplicates-in-a-sorted-java-array

Comment: Why dont you use a `set` which doesn't allow duplicate entries.

Comment: @UmaKanth the set where should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to generate a unique, random list of ints:

```
    new Random().ints(0, 101)// generate a stream of random integers from 0 (incl.) to 100
            .distinct() // unique                                   
            .limit(20) // we only need 20 random numbers
            .sorted() // sort
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

So if you want the same result as in your old code, this is your complete new code:

```
class UniqueRandomIntArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Random().ints(0, 101).distinct() // generate a stream of random
            // integers
            .limit(20) // we only need 20 random numbers
            .sorted().forEach((int i) -> System.out.print(" | " + i));
    System.out.println(" | ");
}
} // class ends
```

Comment: So this the new array or I have to put this inside the code?

Comment: @RexYou do you need the array? you can change the code above. instead of .forEach(...) you can write .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());. This gives you a List of Integers. you can convert it to an array if you really need it

Comment: But I don't know where to change?

Comment: @RexYou I've updated my answer. ask if you need more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code with your current main method and run the program.
for ascending order result use this
Arrays.sort(result);        

for descending order result use both
  Arrays.sort(result);          
  Arrays.sort(result, Collections.reverseOrder());

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arra = new int[20];
      uriArray(arra);

      Integer[] result = new Integer[arra.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(arra[i]);
        }       
      Arrays.sort(result);          
      Arrays.sort(result, Collections.reverseOrder());  //comment this line if you want only ascending order results. if you want descending order result keep this line alive

      for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++)  {
         System.out.print(" | " + result[i]);
         }
      System.out.println(" | ");
      }
```

Let me know if this works for you

**Include these packages**

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

Comment: The arrays didn't work so what is your suggestion?Main.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
      Arrays.sort(result);          
      ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class UniqueRandomIntArray
Main.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
      Arrays.sort(result, Collections.reverseOrder());
                          ^
  symbol:   variable Collections
  location: class UniqueRandomIntArray
Main.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
      Arrays.sort(result, Collections.reverseOrder());
      ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class UniqueRandomIntArray

Comment: did you include these packages? import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

Comment: which editor are you using for development?...are you using any IDE for development like eclipse ?

Comment: include the above packages I mentioned and run the program..it will work.. I have updated it in my answer also

Comment: Thank you very much... I want to ask you something.... Last time I use the  Collections.shuffle didn't useful just because I didn't import?

Comment: yes I guess...what was the error? ... which editor are you using for development?

Comment: I use for random choose number...the error same as just now...THANK YOU VERY MUCH...